# ASP core Web API post always giving null data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Here is my Model

```
    public class Country
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my controller

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public TestController()
    {

    }


[HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Country country)
    {
            return StatusCode(500, "");
    }

}
```

When i test my controller through PostMan using following data, **why country object is always null**. Here is the data i am sending through postman. My break point is hitting that means API is running fine, its just that i am not getting my data there.

I selected "raw" and JSON("application/json") on POSTMAN to send following data

```
{
     "id": "1",
     "name": "ddd",
     "abbreviation": "ate"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id is a [GUID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx) but you are passing it an Integer you have two options either change id to an integer like:

```
public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
}
```

or pass a GUID via postman.

```
{
 "id": "593d7c22-893c-474f-9df8-00e219074cb8",
 "name": "ddd",
 "abbreviation": "ate"
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I thought it should atleast fill in other fields, but seems it is ignoring everything.